# IntellijIdea doesn't recognize classes inside a jar in network

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jar

In my pom.xml file I want to add a dependency that's in the network so I did as following:

```
<properties>
        <rai.home>\\iis\runner</rai.home>
</properties>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.rai.utilities</groupId>
    <artifactId>rai-utilities</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${rai.home}/jar/rai-utilities-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

When I run mvn clean install this works just fine, but IntellijIdea fails to find classes in that jar, I get an error: `java.package ... does not exist`

If I changed the path and use the same jar in my local machine, like this:

```
<systemPath>D:/jar/rai-utilities-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
```

IntellijIdea recognizes the classes inside this jar.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA [has no support for the UNC paths](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219060) in the dependencies, you can use the mapped drive as a workaround and reference the file by the mapped drive letter.